# Как вынести слова которые начинаются на $ с помощью регулярного выражения POSIX?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql, posix, plpgsql

Мне приходит строка `'($param1+$param2)/$param3'`

Я хочу составить массив `{ (, $param1, +, $param2, ), /, $param3 }`

Я нашел функцию `regexp_split_to_array()`, но не могу придумать регулярное выражение, которое бы мне помогло.

Я пользуюсь postgreSQL 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
select regexp_matches('($param1+$param2)/$param3', '\$\w+|[^\w\s]', 'g')
```

Для получения массива используйте

```
select array(
    select (regexp_matches('($param1+$param2)/$param3', '\$\w+|[^\w\s]', 'g'))[1]
)
```

**Подробности**

- `\$\w+` - символ `$` и 1 и более букво-цифровых символов (включая символ подчёркивания)
- `|` - или
- `[^\w\s]` - любой символ, отличный от букво-цифрового и пробельного символа  и символа подчёркивания.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я очень благодарен Вам за ответ. Я совсем недавно начал изучать postgresql11 и еще многое не знаю. Ваш пример, безусловно, работает, но мне нужно немного другое. Мне нужно получить именно массив элементов типа text, чтобы потом пробегаться по нему и выполнять с элементами некоторые операции. Поэтому мне нужно использовать regexp_split_to_array(), а эта функция ругается, когда я пытаюсь использовать Ваше регулярное выражение (ERROR: regexp_split_to_array does not support the global option)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (IN text) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
  _text_of_formulas ALIAS FOR $1;
  _arr_of_formulas text[];
  _result text[];
BEGIN
  FOR _arr_of_formulas IN SELECT regexp_matches(_text_of_formulas, '\$\w+|[^\w\s]', 'g')
  LOOP
    IF(_result IS NULL) THEN
      _result :=  _arr_of_formulas;
    ELSE
      _result := _result || _arr_of_formulas;
    END IF;
  END LOOP; 
RETURN _result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score -1):

Найти все вхождения регулярки `\$\w+|(?:[^$]|\$\$)+`:

```js
console.log('($param1+$param2)/$param3'.match(/\$\w+|(?:[^$]|\$\$)+/g))
```